# javascript keydown not working in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, event-handling, cross-browser, keydown

In a table , I simulate selected row by changing style of the row .Now I want to move this selected row by arrow keys but the keydown event is not working in Chrome and Firefox.

I do NOT want to use JQuery.

Also(if possible) because I render this table on serverside in a complicated process it is better to use inline event hanlder not attach with javascript (I mean using < tr onkeydown="myfunc(this)" > ... )

Comment: your current attempt is so clean, I can hardly see it...

Comment: why these negetive votes? (keydown is not working on TR element in chrome and firefox).

Comment: Isn't `keydown` a Jquery event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should use onkeydown on the table rows.
Keydown on rows only works if you have an input element inside them. otherwise they can't be focused.

Don't know if that is feasible in your case, but you could try it like this. if for whatever reason you don't want to use jQuery you'll have to modify it a bit for browsers which don't support querySelector:

```
document.body.addEventListener('keydown',function(ev){
    var trs = document.querySelector('.s');
    if(ev.keyCode == 38 && trs.previousSibling){
        trs.className = '';
        trs.previousSibling.className = 's';
    }else if(ev.keyCode == 40 && trs.nextSibling){
        trs.className = '';
        trs.nextSibling.className = 's';
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FvgaE/

Comment: You don't need to have an input element to have focus.

Comment: you are right Neil, but why "<tr onkeydown="foo()" >" is not working?

Comment: @Neil right it should work with an `a` as well. but it doesn't work on a plain `tr`